# changing image based on day

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am bringing in an image on my index page (for a fullscreen website) through css

css

```
.indx-BG { background: url('...') no-repeat center center; }
```

However, I want to change the background image based on the day (Monday, Tuesday, etc)I have found sources to change it based on the time of day, I want it to change based on the day itself and am struggling to find any sources

Comment: You want to change it in JS ? If so, you just need to use the class `Date()` and the method `getDay()`

Comment: basically I think Bobby Jack below has the right idea

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499546/changing-the-background-image-based-on-the-day-of-the-week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$images_by_day = array('sunday-image.gif', 'monday-image.gif', ...);
$image_for_today = $images_by_day[date('w')];
```

`date('w')` will give you a number between 0 and 6 that represents the current day of the week. Ensure your `$images_by_day` array contains 7 corresponding elements.

How you use `$image_for_today` is up to you. You could `echo()` the image directly or you could store css class names in the `$images_by_day` instead. You could even reduce the code a bit like so:

CSS:

```
.image-0 { background: url(sundays-image); }
.image-1 { background: url(mondays-image); }
/* etc */
```

PHP:

```
echo '<div class="image-'.date('w').'"></div>';
```

Comment: Ok, so I need to bring my background image in in a better way than through css then. I have an image for everyday of the week, so when it's monday I want the background to be monday's etc

Comment: No, CSS is a fine approach for this - if the image is purely 'decorative'. Did you want the change to occur server-side (e.g. php) or client-side (javascript)?

Comment: Not sure if either is better, I just need to put it as the background of a div, not inside one. So I currently have it in css (background: ...) but I would have to use php as the url since theres multiple ones. Or I can hard code it to the div in html. Just not sure the proper line

Comment: @user3550879 edited my example to be more specific to your case

Comment: Not sure what changed, I want to put it in my css style for #indx-BG if possible. example background-image:url(../img/<?php echo ...  ?>.jpg); just not sure what string to use

Comment: @user3550879 i've tried to include everything you'd need in the CSS and PHP sections above. It's very small, but that's all it needs to be! Your CSS is fixed - you define the classes and each one has the relevant day's image (so replace "sundays-image" with the path to sunday's image). Put the PHP code wherever you need the image in your final page.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
$day = date('w');
$img = $day + 1 ;

?>

<style>
    .your_bg_img{

        background-image:url('images/<?php echo $img ?>.jpg');
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>


<div class="your_bg_img">

</div>
```

I have run this code in my system , it works fine. When I change the date then I get the different image as expected.

1 : store your images in **images** folder and give them name as **1.jpg** , **2.jpg** and so on up to **7.jpg**

2 : after that run this code in your file.

if day number is 1 then it will give the image of **1.jpg** to `background-image` property and it will display on the screen.

I have checked in my system . I get two different images on two different day.

[image: Image on 6th January]

[image: Image on 7th January]

This way you can change the image per day.

Hope this helps.

If you are still not getting then let me know. I 'll be ready to help you out.

Comment: Ok, question then. my images are in a folder ( called 'img') and depending on what level it's being called determines what sub-groups i need, example  ../img/monday.jpg or not. where would I put ../img/ in the html php or css php

Comment: so far I haven't been able to have anything show up

Comment: I have updated again. kindly check if it works for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
<?php
    if(date('l')=='Monday') {
?>
    .indx-BG { background: url('...') no-repeat center center; }
<?php
    }
?>
</style>
```

same repeat for all days