# Changing the background image based on the day of the week

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to change a div's background image based on the day of the week. The images are in a folder named 'img' I have the following code;

html

```
<?php
  $images_by_day = array('monday.jpg', 'tuesday.jpg', 'wednesday.jpg',  ...);
  $image_for_today = $images_by_day[date('w')];
?>

<div class="jumbotron indx-BG">
   //content
</div>
```

css (external style sheet)

```
.indx-BG {
  background: url('../img/<?php echo $image_for_today ?>.jpg') no-repeat center center;
 }
```

Comment: You can't use PHP inside of a CSS file. Echo the variable in the `style` attribute of the `div` like Sjors said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better you define seven different classes with different background images within the css file and then apply those classes within the elements using php file.

Like:

```
<div class="container <?php echo date('l')?>-bg" id="indx-jumbo">
   //content
</div>
```

And in your css file you define css classes like:

```
.monday-bg {
  background: url('../img/image_for_monday.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
.tuesday-bg {
  background: url('../img/image_for_tuesday.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
.
.
.
.sunday-bg {
  background: url('../img/image_for_sunday.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: Well not sure why, but yours seems to work, I can't get the the others to

Comment: better approach as in that using classes for different days you can use it by just defining it at one place and using classes are always preferred over defining styles inline.

Comment: In above code there is very less to do @server end, things are managed using classes only.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use PHP in a CSS file. A way to solve this problem is by adding the background-image inline, something like this:

```
<div class="container" id="indx-jumbo" style="background-image: url('../img/<?php echo $image_for_today ?>.jpg')">
   //content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PHP in css file. You can add `background image` inline. Please check following code.

```
<div class="container" id="indx-jumbo" style="background-image: url('../img/<?php echo date( "l", $timestamp); ?>.jpg')">
   //content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $images_by_day = array('sunday.jpg','monday.jpg', 'tuesday.jpg',
                        'wednesday.jpg','thursday.jpg','friday.jpg','saturday.jpg');
 $image_for_today = $images_by_day[date('w')];
?>


<div class="container" id="indx-jumbo" 
style=" background: url('../img/<?php echo $image_for_today ?>') no-repeat center center;">
 //Content
</div>
```

Comment: u hav imgs named ' sunday.jpg ' and others... The same work i have done in www.dealznmealz.com at discount baskets.... u can see for refference.

Comment: inline css have higher priority than same css  in external stylesheet...

Comment: Ya i'm not sure. There's no errors, just no image showing up. Does the php have to go somewhere special for it to work?

Comment: the background url says it has the right image but doesn't show up

Comment: just check height width in css

Comment: have u tried this by removing ../ from inline  it will work i just now checked it....

Comment: I've tried removing ../ and it doesn't show, I've tried hardcoding just a regular image (no php) and it just doesn't want to show. Your code targets properly it's jsut inlining the image seems not to show. It does when defined in css

Comment: Got exact solution u needed... just remove single quot ( ' ) from url... E.g.  url(img/<?php echo $image_for_today ?>)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this.

```
<?php
  $images_by_day = array('monday.jpg', 'tuesday.jpg', 'wednesday.jpg', 'thursday.jpg','friday.jpg','saturday.jpg','sunday.jpg');
  $today = date('l');
  foreach ($images_by_day as $key => $value) {
    $day = substr($value,0,-4);
    $str = strcasecmp($day, $today);

    if($str == '0'){
        $background = $value;
    }
  }
?>

<div class="container" id="indx-jumbo" style="background-image: url('../img/<?= $background; ?>');">
   //content
</div>
```

Comment: Close, The code seems to detect the day properly, however it just posts the word 'friday' or the day as text

Comment: Still no image, but the Text has disappeared, is it something in the background-image code

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your image name contains day of a week. You can do it easily with php's substring inbuilt functions.

```
<?php
foreach($imagArray as $image)
{
    if(strpos($image,date('l'))
    {
       //display image and exit
    }

}

?>
```